# CA1062: ValidateArgumentsOfPublicMethods on co-constructor calls

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, fxcop, ca1062

I have a class with two constructors that look like this:

```
public MyClass(SomeOtherClass source) : this(source, source.Name) { }
public MyClass(SomeOtherClass source, string name) { /* ... */ }
```

When I run FxCop, it correctly reports a violation of [CA1062: ValidateArgumentsOfPublicMethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182182.aspx), because if `source` is `null` in the first constructor, it will throw a `NullReferenceException` on `source.Name`.

Is there any way to fix this warning?

I could make an extension method that checks for null and returns its argument, but it would be ugly.  Also, as I understand, it wouldn't resolve the warning because FxCop wouldn't realize what it does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this?

```
public MyClass(SomeOtherClass source) : this(source, source == null ? null : source.Name) { }
public MyClass(SomeOtherClass source, string name) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. You can use any static method also.

Comment: Unfortunately this is rather unwieldy when a single parameter constructor uses its parameter value's properties to pass values as arguments for another constructor with many parameters (e.g. converting JavaScript-style "parameter object" to scalar parameters). I wish C# allowed for `static`-scoped code to run before a superclass' constructor so complex validation logic can be applied.

Answer (score 1):

There are legitimate times to turn off FxCop warnings and this could very well be one, but you can correct the problem by either a ternary expression that checks for null and throws an exception (or substitutes a default value), or a call to a static method that checks for null and throws the appropriate exception.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was asked some time ago I just want to note with the later features in C# you can now also use this:

```
public MyClass(SomeOtherClass source) : this(source, source?.Name) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since C# 7.0 you can also do this:

```
public MyClass(SomeOtherClass source) : this(source?.Name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source))) { }
```

C# 7.0 allows throwing exceptions as expressions. (See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#throw-expressions))

Answer (score 0):

I would say the only way to fix this warning would be to turn it off.  FxCop is a great tool but sometimes you need to remember that it is just a tool and can make suggestions that are not always fitting to your code.

In this example I would say ignore the warning or disable it if you don't want to see it.